# Why is php decimal-ext throwing an exception for wrong return type of compareTo method?

Tags: laravel, decimal

I've installed decimal-ext extension and php-decimal/laravel composer package. I'm using it to compare large decimal numbers. On my laptop everything works correctly but on my staging server the following error is thrown:

`Return value of Decimal\Decimal::compareTo() must be of the type int, none returned`

and here is the code:

```
(new Decimal($value))->compareTo($maxNumber) == -1;
```

As I said I'm not getting this error on my laptop.

Laravel: 5.8
PHP: 7.4.3
Server: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time on this but figured it out. The decimal-ext extension was not loaded in the server's php.ini file. Php didn't throw an exception about missing extension but about the wrong return type because the class Decimal was actually loaded (it was installed via the composer). I could instantiate an instance but the implementation was missing:

```
/**
 * Ordering
 *
 * This method is equivalent to the `<=>` operator.
 *
 * @param mixed $other
 *
 * @return int  0 if this decimal is considered is equal to $other,
 *             -1 if this decimal should be placed before $other,
 *              1 if this decimal should be placed after $other.
 */
 public function compareTo($other): int {}
```